# Why Java Unix time and Calendar calculate exact time?

Tags: java, calendar, unix-timestamp, leap-second

I heard that Unix time does not include **"Leap Second".** And I also heard that Java Calendar API does not include Leap second.

Since 1972, 27 seconds were added as the Leap second. And Unix time began 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (UTC).

So, I thought that there are 27 seconds difference between current UTC time and Unix time.

To clarify my thought, I did some experiment like below. 1614766198 was a Unix time at 2021-03-03 10:10:00 (UTC+0)

```java
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.TimeZone;

public class CanendarTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {

        Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("UTC"));
        
        cal.setTimeInMillis(1614766198L * 1000);
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MONTH));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.MINUTE));
        System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.SECOND));
    }
}
```

The result of above code was

```
output
2021
2
3
10
9
58
```

Output seems like "2021-03-03 10:09:58".

So, My Question is that, Why Java Calendar API return 2 second difference from 1970-01-01 00:00:00 (UTC) not 27 second difference?

Comment: I recommend you don’t use `Calendar`. That class is poorly designed and long outdated. Instead use `Instant` from [java.time, the modern Java date and time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/).

Comment: You are wrong, sorry. 1614766198 does equal Wednesday 3. March 2021 10:09:58 UTC. [Check yourself here.](https://www.epochconverter.com/). The Unix timestamp for 2021-03-03 10:10:00 (UTC+0) would have to end on a couple of zeros.

Comment: @OleV.V. Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Leap seconds are meant to be ignored in the context of a calendar (years, months, days). Days are not *exactly* 24 hours long. To maintain the illusion that days are 24 hours long, every few years we slow our clocks (spinning of the earth on its axis) a second to keep in sync with the calendar (earth orbiting the sun). So both Unix time and *java.time* classes purposely ignore, or “swallow”, the leap second.  (P.S. Never use the terrible `Calendar` & `Date` classes.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1614766198 was a Unix time at 2021-03-03 10:10:00 (UTC+0)

This is not correct. The following UNIX command

```
TZ=UTC date -r 1614766198
```

outputs

```
Wed  3 Mar 2021 10:09:58 UTC
```

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.Instant;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Instant instant = Instant.ofEpochSecond(1614766198);
        System.out.println(instant);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2021-03-03T10:09:58Z
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/ewyG6E)

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) represents an instantaneous point on the timeline in [UTC](https://www.timeanddate.com/worldclock/timezone/utc). The `Z` in the output is the [timezone designator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Time_zone_designators) for a zero-timezone offset. It stands for Zulu and specifies the `Etc/UTC` timezone (which has the timezone offset of `+00:00` hours).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>